# Automatic field should take the required entry

Tags: sharepoint-online

We are preparing a Asset request list in sharepoint.
We have different department with specific system configuration.
For Ex, If user will select "sales department" automatic the system configuration field should taken required system configuration details.

For Ex: Department : Sales
        System configuration: i5,8GB RAM, 512GB SSD.

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

You can create cascading of Lookup Dropdown Fields to achieve your requirement.

For more detailed information, refer to the following article:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/cascading-of-lookup-dropdown-fields-on-sharepoint-2013-and-o/